# trying to use a news API with rails application

Tags: api, open-uri

I'm trying to get information from newsapi. I've used the basic structure i found elsewhere for another api to start with but i'm very new to this and not sure what is wrong/how to fix etc. all i'm trying to do is display the titles of the articles on my index page. At the moment, everything displays on the page, like title, author etc as an array but i just want to narrow things down and the syntax for doing so in the view. i've changed my api key to '?' for the time being(i know it should be in the .env file).ive looked at a lot of docs but i cant seem to find an answer. apologies if
 this is a broad question.

[image]

```html
class TestsController < ApplicationController
require "open-uri"
  def index

  url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=????????????????????????'
  article_serialized = open(url).read
  @articles = JSON.parse(article_serialized)
  end
end
```

```html
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<%= article[1] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by narrow things down?

Comment: as in only display the title of the article, and not everything. ive added a screenshot of what is currently showing. @HassanVoyeau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
<% @articles["articles"].each do |article| %>
<%= article["title"] %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Edit** : This is what my ruby script looks like that I used for testing

```
require 'json'
file = File.read 'output.json'
data = JSON.parse(file)

data["articles"].each do |item|
    print item["title"]
end
```

Comment: it now has a different error, "undefined method `title' for ["status", "ok"]:Array", after i added your code. its highlighting the article.title

Comment: Modified the code. I actually tested this time, but from a ruby script reading from json file with the json copied from here https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines